# Отслеживать посещения по IP

Tags: php, ip

Как на PHP сделать подсчет посещений по iP? На сайте есть задание, которое можно выполнить не более 5 раз, и нужно чтобы при входе с помощью `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];` я получал ip пользователя и привязывал к этому ip единицу и при повторном прохождении страницы он увеличивал значение на 1. И по достижении 5 я делаю так, что задание не выполняется. Сама проблема связать ip с цифрой(кол-вом посещений данной страницы).

Comment: То есть не важно, что IP может быть динамическим? Кто пришел с ip тот и пришел?

Comment: создать таблицу и считать все ip, либо считать все ip, либо обновлять количество просмотров (было 0 - ставим 1, было 1 - ставим 2)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, нет

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, в данном случае, не важно. В одной сессии он маловероятно что поменяется, значит такое подходит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

создаем таблицу `tablename` с колонками `ip` и `count`

страница:

```
 <?php
$ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];

$check = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT `ip` FROM `tablename` WHERE `ip` = '" . $ip . "'"));

if ($check == 0) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `tablename` SET `ip` = '" . $ip . "',  `count` = '1'");
    $check['count'] = 1;
} else {
    mysql_query("UPDATE `tablename` SET `count` = `count` + 1 WHERE `ip` = '" . $ip . "'");
}

if ($check['count'] < 5) {
    echo 'показывает то что нужно';
}
```

Comment: А еще у `mysql` (что в данном случае уместно) можно писать запрос `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`....... на будущее ;)  Ну и расширение `mysql` не испольовать

Comment: И еще добавьте cookie, вдруг пользователь сменил IP, и желательно информацию о браузере и ОС.